# Is android assets folder a real folder in the file system

Tags: android

After an APK is installed, does the assets folder get unpacked to a physical folder on the file system or does it stay in the APK? If it is unpacked, where does it go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It stays within the APK.  You can think of the APK as a zipped file, with the assets folder inside the zip.

Comment: You can easily access files in the assets folder using the AssetManager.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html